# Git adding file having space in name

Tags: git, github

I am trying to update my file, but I was unable to do so because of file name contains two words

```
$ git add 00162808_LirajMaharjan_CP_Design/Class diagram.mdj
```

Error:

```
fatal: pathspec '00162808_LirajMaharjan_CP_Design/Class' did not match any files
```

Can I add a file like 'Class diagram/mdj' with spaces in the name?

Comment: Instead of commenting 'thank you' to each answer, upvote those that you find useful (and accept the one you think answers your question best)

Answer (score 7):

Either escape the space with a backslash:

```
git add 00162808_LirajMaharjan_CP_Design/Class\ diagram.mdj
```

Or quote the filename:

```
git add "00162808_LirajMaharjan_CP_Design/Class diagram.mdj"
```

Single quotes work too:

```
git add '00162808_LirajMaharjan_CP_Design/Class diagram.mdj'
```

Comment: Single quote doesn't work in case of windows, so for windows go with double quotes.

Comment: what if there are multiple spaces in a row?

Answer (score 1):

Try
`git add 00162808_LirajMaharjan_CP_Design/Class\ diagram.mdj`